# How can I format my numbers in such a way that the digits are grouped?

Tags: java

I am developing a game using LibGDX, how can I make the label look like that:

```
Current display:    1000000000
Desired display: 1 000 000 000
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not calling it every frame, parsing it out with `substring` is probably the easiest approach:

```
public static String groupByThrees(String s){
    String result = "";
    int index = s.length();
    // append groups of three to the front
    while(index-3 > 0){
        result = s.substring(index-3, index) + " " + result;
        index -= 3;
    }
    // handle any partial group at the very beginning
    if(index >= 0){
        result = s.substring(0, index) + " " + result;
    }
    // remove the training space at the end
    if(result.length() > 0){
        result = result.substring(0, result.length()-1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @mustafacreative04 You're welcome. If this (or some other answer for that matter) solved your problem, please [mark it as the accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) - it helps others with similar problems find working solutions.

Answer (score 1):

A naive approach would be to divide and modulus by 1000 until nothing is left (pseudo code):

```
number = 1000000000
groupedString = ""

do {
  leftOver = number % 1000 // This will give you the value of the three right-most digits
  number = number / 1000 // This will keep the left-most digits for the next group; make sure this is an int division
  stringLeftOver = Integer.toString(leftOver)  // Convert to string what has to be pre-pended

  if number > 0
    // More groups to come, left pad with 0's
    properlyPadded = "000".substring(stringLeftOver.length()) + stringLeftOver
  else
    properlyPadded = stringLeftOver

  if groupedString.length() == 0
    // first time here, we just used the padded string
    groupedString = properlyPadded
  else
    // second time here (and more), prepend the string and add a separating space
    groupedString += properlyPadded + " " + groupedString
} while ( while number > 0 )
```

---

**Alternatively**, just use the Java `String` class:

```
groupedString = String.format(Locale.US, "%,d", number).replace(',', ' ')
```

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12682507))

---

*Note that both of these methods have not been tested. Last time I coded in Java was more than 10 years ago.*

*Caveat:* I'd make sure that the label is wide enough and/or that the text wrap is disabled. (Again, I have no experience with LibGDX, but that's something to be aware of.)